# Java Class subclass variable reference

Tags: java, class

I keep running into the 'cannot find symbol' error on my class.  The variable is clearly declared in the super class, yet the subclass can not see it.  I receive no errors except on the new constructor of `JLabel` in the subclass `RecordViewer`.

```
 class RecordViewer extends JDialog{
     private JButton next;
     private JButton prev;
     private JLabel label;
     private int current;

     public RecordViewer(CDinventoryItem [] array){
         super();
         current = 0;
         final CDinventoryItem [] items = array;

         label = new JLabel(items[getCurrent()]);
```

Predefined toString from my CDinventoryItem class...

```
        @Override public String toString(){

        //  Decimal foramting for the inventory values
        NumberFormat dformat = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

        //  Formatting for the inventory output
        StringBuilder ouput  = new StringBuilder();
        String New_Line = System.getProperty("line.separator");

            ouput.append("The product number of my CD is: ").append(iPitemNumber).append (New_Line);
            ouput.append("The title of the CD is: ").append(sPtitle).append (New_Line);
            ouput.append("I have ").append(iPnumberofUnits).append(" units in stock.").append (New_Line);
            ouput.append("The total value of my inventory on this product is: ").append(dformat.format(stockValue())).append (New_Line);
            return ouput.toString();
        }
```

Comment: Please provide the whole error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that the standard Java JLabel? You are trying to pass an object of type CDinventoryItem, and the JLabel won't have a constructor to handle that kind of argument, unless it is extending the String or Icon classes.

Comment: Yes just the standard JLabel.  CDinventory class is an array of String, int, int, double

Comment: So it doesn't extend the String or Icon class? Then the constructor isn't going to work. extend doesn't mean it contains a String variable/array of Strings as a member field, it means you used the keyword extend in your class declaration; CDinventory would then be a subclass of String. That probably isn't what you are trying to do though- maybe you want to do something like items[getCurrent()].getName() as your argument, where getName would be some method returning a String.

Comment: OK a label = this.setLabel(items[Current()]); removed the error. I let NetBeans create a method for the setLabel.

Comment: Thank you.  But I still am running into another error.  You are referring to the other problem I am having as well.                 getLabel().setText(items[getCurrent()]);  returns a 'cannot be applied to given types'.  I just want it to display the array in the JLabel, but tells me I cannot because it is of String type.

Comment: Again, this is because a CDinventoryItem isn't a String. That method expects a String as an argument. You need to make a method for the CDinventoryItem class that returns a String containing whatever text you need for the JLabel, and then have that method called as the argument for setText

Comment: Yikes.  Ok...  so there is no way to return an array using JLabel.  Sorry I am Java noob.  Can you give me an example or reference some material so I can learn how to build a method to turn the CDinventoryItem into a String.

Comment: I already have a toString method in my CDinventoryItem class.  can I use it to parse the object into a string so I can pass it to JLabel?

Comment: The toString method is in fact one common to all classes in Java. You can use it, but it might not do what you want. A good thing to try is overriding it by defining your own version of the toString method. This is commonly done.

Comment: I have defined it already to format the output in my CDinventoryItem class.  I will add it to the code above.

Comment: OK a    getLabel().setText(items[getCurrent()].toString());  removed the error.

Comment: OK nevermind it IS returning the information from the CDinventory class.  However it isn't formating it properly, and it is giving a blank JDialog window.  Once I click next it displays the information, just all of it running together.  This is crazy.

Comment: Should I try formatting my toString differently?  Or should it work?

Answer (score 2):

- organize your imports, so that `JLabel` is imported properly
- `JLabel` does not define a constructor taking your custom type. You need to pass a string there.

Comment: Yes i have the import javax.swing.*; at the top.  I just added the import javax.swing.JLabel; as you suggested.  Still no change.

Comment: @user569127 are you using an IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but your question wording implies you're trying to use a private field directly from a subclass? private fields can't be seen anywhere other than the class that they're declared in, including classes in the same inheritance hierarchy. You could make it protected, but this is frowned upon - better to either provide a mutator method to label or better still, initialise it in the superclass constructor.

Comment: Yes even if I initialize it in the superclass it doesn't see it.  Was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: OK a    label = this.setLabel(items[Current()]);     removed the error.  I let NetBeans create a method for the setLabel.